# What is wrong with this $lookup query ?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a 2 large collection and i am trying to join both using the $lookup command.

This is literally the query. But i am always getting Illegal char error. What am i missing here?

```
db.alerts.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: “description”,
          localField: “AtkName”,
          foreignField: “AtkName”,
          as: “desc”
        }
   }
])
```

What is wrong with this lookup query ?

Getting the following error.

```
E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):5:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a different set of characters for quotation marks which are causing the error as Mongo only recognises a certain type.

Consider the following characters:

```
"   U+0022 QUOTATION MARK              <---- the correct quotation mark to use
“   U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
”   U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
```

You should use the `"   U+0022 QUOTATION MARK` i.e.

```
db.alerts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "description",
            localField: "AtkName",
            foreignField: "AtkName"
            as: "desc"
        }
    }
])
```

For more details, check out the Unicode.org "confusables" tool which finds [15 characters similar to "](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=%22&r=None).

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I was using different editors and some how the query got messed up.  :)